# android howto include the encryption Public Key in the apk source code since the device cannot load it from file

Tags: android, encryption

In the code below im creating public
and Private Keys for encryption.

I really would like to embed the Public Key in the Android java source code.

Since they are Object's I don't understand how to include the Public Key in the code.
I have tried to create some final String but that did not work

Any help would be appreciated.
Maybe this is a bad ide since i dont see much talk about it

```
public void GenerateKeyPair()
{       
    try{
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(
                kp.getPublic(),RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec
        (kp.getPrivate(),RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

        saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(),pub.getPublicExponent());
    saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(),priv.getPrivateExponent());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void saveToFile(String fileName,BigInteger mod, 
        BigInteger exp) throws Exception {

    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream
    (new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    try {
        oout.writeObject(mod);
        oout.writeObject(exp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("error", e);
    } finally {
        oout.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering my own question.

```
// create the string for client to use
byte[] b = Base64.encodeBase64(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
String encodedString = new String(b);
System.out.println(encodedString);
```